# Can I send ERC20 and ETH in the same transaction trough web3js?

Tags: web3js, wallet-transfer, transferfrom

Can I send ERC20 and ETH in the same transaction trough web3js ?

I want enable the user to send my token with ETH in a same transaction to my wallet. I know that there are 2 transactions (ETH transfer & token transfer). But could it be possible to approve both at the same time?

I do not want the user to accept 3 metamask popups (approve ETH spending, approve token spending, Smart Contract transfer ETH & ERC20 Token function).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need a custom `transfer` method in your token, default transfer method is not payable, so write another `payableTransfer` method to let user send ETH and in web3 set `value` field of transaction to ETH amount and `data` field of transaction to payableTransfer method data

Comment: But that custom method implies creating that it is not exactly an ERC20 and can lead to another issues.

Comment: Exactly, the best way is to do as ERC20 standard